# Reset state of other child components in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a parent component containing an array and I am mapping to create multiple cards something like this->

```
const Users = [
    {
      id: 1,
name: "abc",
age: 12,
    },
    {
      id: 2,
name: "def",
age: 22,
    },
    {
      id: 3,
name: "abf",
age: 32,
    },
  ];

{Users.map((h, index) => {
        return (
          <React.Fragment key={index}>
            <User data={h} />
            <br></br>
          </React.Fragment>
        );
      })}
```

User.js

```
import { useState } from "react";
import "./style.css";

function User(user) {


  const [copyTxt, setCopyTxt] = useState("Copy");
  const [copyClass, setCopyClass] = useState("button_copy");

  const handleCopy = () => {
    setCopyTxt("Copied!");
    setCopyClass("button_copied");
  };

  return (
    <div className="user_div">
      
        <div className="p-2 flex-fill button_div">
          <button type="submit" onClick={handleCopy} className={copyClass}>
            {copyTxt}
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>

  );
}

export default User;
```

`current result` ->
if all 3 buttons are clicked one by one, for all 3 buttons text changes to `Copied!`

`expected result` ->
if all 3 buttons are clicked one by one, the last button clicked should be the only one that shows `Copied!`, but Other buttons should show `Copy`.

How do I achieve that?

Comment: Looks like your code will work. What's the problem?

Comment: all buttons start saying copied

Comment: The code shown [already does this](https://codesandbox.io/s/interesting-keller-yzwg3s?file=/src/App.js).  Can you provide a runnable [mcve] which demonstrates the problem?  What even is the problem?

Comment: @David i have updated the description with current and expected results pls let me know if anything else needed

Comment: @Mr_Sharma: Ah, that's a different question then.  It sounds like what you want is to "lift state up" from the `<User>` component to its parent component.  That higher-level component would manage the state for all of the data used by the `<User>` components, and pass that state (and a state setter function) to those child components as props.

Comment: @David can you please write the code for achieving state lift?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this

First you create a state in the parent component from the array and add the property `isCopied` to each one and set it default to `false`:

```js
const [usersState, setUsersState] = useState(
  Users.map((user) => {
    return {
      ...user,
      isCopied: false,
    };
  })
)
```

Also there, you create the function that takes the id of the user from the child component and set its property `isCopied` to `true` but `false` for all others:

```js
const handleCopy = (id) => {
  setUsersState((prev) =>
    prev.map((h) => {
      if (h.id === id) {
        return { ...h, isCopied: true };
      } else {
        return { ...h, isCopied: false };
      }
    })
  );
}
```

Now to each child you pass as props, data ( the user + `isCopied` property) and also the `handleCopy` function:

```js
return (
  <>
    {usersState.map((h) => {
      return (
        <React.Fragment key={h.id}>
          <User data={h} handleCopy={handleCopy} />
          <br></br>
        </React.Fragment>
      );
    })}
  </>
)
```

Finally, in the child component, you want to update its state (`copyTxt` and `copyClass`) each time property `isCopied` of the passed user (`data`) is updated, because it depend only on that:

```js
function User({ data, handleCopy }) {
  const [copyTxt, setCopyTxt] = useState();
  const [copyClass, setCopyClass] = useState();

  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    if (data.isCopied == true) {
      setCopyTxt("Copied!");
      setCopyClass("button_copied");
    } else {
      setCopyTxt("Copy!");
      setCopyClass("button_copy");
    }
  }, [data.isCopied]); 

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <button
          type="submit"
          onClick={() => {
            handleCopy(data.id);
          }}
          className={copyClass}
        >
          {copyTxt}
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: works. much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is **life the state up**.

```
function Parent() {
const Users = [
    {
    id: 1,
    name: "abc",
    age: 12,
    },
    {
    id: 2,
    name: "def",
    age: 22,
    },
    {
    id: 3,
    name: "abf",
    age: 32,
    },
];

const [active,setActive] = useState(null);

return (
    <>
        {Users.map((d)=>(
            <User data={d} active={active} setActive={setActive}/>
        ))}
    </>
)
}

function User({data,active,setActive}){
    function handleCopy(){
        setActive(data.id);
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <span>{user.name}</span>
            <button onClick={handleCopy}>
                {active===data.id ? "Copied" : "Copy"}
            </button>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Logic is simple store the active id at one place.